# '>' vs '+' in describing 'larger/more than'

Tags: symbols

If I wanted to use a symbol to describe the weight being 'more than' 10kg. Which of the following is more appropriate?

```
When weight is > 10 kg
```

or

```
When weight is 10+ kg
```

Comment: In Math you do the > version.  But perhaps not in English?  Actually in English you write it out: "more than ten kg".  I guess I only see "10+" in on-line shorthand; you should not assume everyone knows what it means.

Comment: I'd agree that while > is well known in maths, I've come across non-mathematical people who don't know the difference between > and <.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about standard everyday English (see GEdgar's comment). It could well be on-topic at Mathematics.SE as part of standard maths shorthand.

Comment: Even if we accept those writing conventions, which many of us do as we often see them used in magazine articles and such, your question is moot. That's because you're asking which is more appropriate, as if they mean the same thing when they don't. Writing "When weight is > 10 kg" isn't the same as writing "When weight is 10+ kg" because "> 10 kg" means "more than 10 kilograms" but "10+ kg" means "10 or more kilograms." "10+ kg" includes 10 kilograms, but "> 10 kg" doesn't. It'd have to say "≥ 10kg" to be the same as "10+ kg," but unlike "+" and ">," "≥" isn't conventionally used in writing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking to choose which is more appropriate of two given choices based on a false assumption or premise that the two choices mean the same thing when they don't mean the same thing. It's like asking which of two apples is better when one of them isn't an apple at all but an orange. So I'm voting to close because this is a loaded question in that it is based on the false premise that "> 10 kg" means the same thing as "10+ kg." They aren't equal choices. The more appropriate one would be whichever one means what's intended.

Comment: Were an airline to post, "When weight is > 10 kg, a bag cannot be a carry-on but must be checked," then passengers having a carry-on bag weighing exactly 10 kg **ARE NOT** made to check the bag. Were an airline to instead post, "When weight 10+ kg, a bag cannot be a carry-on but must be checked," then passengers having a carry-on bag weighing exactly 10 kg **ARE** made to check the bag. You may think the distinction is splitting hairs, but trust me, it isn't. If an airline posted "> 10 kg," then tried to make passengers with a carry-on weighing 10 kg check them, there'd be hell to pay.

Answer (score 1):

In Math you do the > version.
But perhaps not in English? Actually in English you write it out: "more than ten kg".
I guess I only see "10+" in on-line shorthand; you should not assume everyone knows what it means.

Answer (score 1):

No one writes *When weight is > 10 kg*. It looks awkward as you're using a mix of mathematical symbols and english words (in this case, the word *is*) together.

If you are to use >, you would write *When weight > 10 kg*, no need for is. If you are to use normal English, 10+ would usually look better.